# Will these two methods of accessing the array implemented identically or not?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, compiler-construction, implementation

We have a three-byte array like below:

```
char charArray[3];
charArray[1]='a';
//or
char * charP=charArray;
charP[1]='a';
```

Two methods are used to access to second element of array, now will they be implemented in the same way by compiler or the first method will not involve a pointer like second method?

Comment: Compile that, and look at the disassembled code. ASM may be a pain to write but it's not that hard to read. (OTOH that will only give you an inconclusive or definitive no answer.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> will they be implemented in the same way by compiler

Maybe.

If you use the name of an array and the subscript is a constant expression, a compiler can probably do some or all of the pointer arithmetic at compile-time.  It might not be able to do the same using a pointer to an array; that probably depends on whether or not the compiler can tell for sure that the pointer points to an element in the array.

This is just speculation, though.  The only way to tell for sure whether a given compiler emits the same code for both is to look at the code emitted by that compiler.

Comment: +1... Nitpick: the code emitted by "your compiler" doesn't tell anything about what "a given compiler" emits... ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Semantically, they'll behave the same - the second element will be set - but it's not specified as to how the compiler will achieve that.

It's possible the compiler could choose to implement the first array access as a pointer reference with an offset, and do the same for the second.  On the other hand, it might optimize the locally allocated array access and directly reference the appropriate memory location - and again, it may do the same optimization on the second access, but it might not.  The options it has depend on the binary platform being compiled for, and whether it "realizes" that the array or pointer actually point to a local variable (which you'd expect it to).

Since you cannot tell the difference anyhow, **you can generally *consider* them to be identical**, even if the implementation happens to differ.

Answer (score 1):

The second method may make the compiler generate more code. charP is a pointer and needs a variable for it, although with that small amount of code there may be a compiler optimisation.

with charP, it is an l-value and you can move it to point to another location and you can increment it with ++, etc.

Answer (score 0):

*Look and see!*

Examine the assembly code that your compiler generates with different optimization levels. I guarantee you'll learn a lot that way.